# How to get TLS 1.3 on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a service deployed in Google Kubernetes Engine and have gotten the request to support TLS 1.3 connections on that service. Currently I do not get higher than TLS 1.2. Do I need to define my ingress differently?

My ingress is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-tls-__CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG__
  namespace: __KUBE_NAMESPACE__
  labels:
    app: __CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG__
    ref: __CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG__
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - __SERVICE_TLS_ENDPOINT__
    secretName: __CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG__-service-cert
  rules:
  - host: __SERVICE_TLS_ENDPOINT__
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service-__CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG__
          servicePort: 8080
```

Master version 1.17.13-gke.600
Pool version 1.17.13-gke.600

Answer (score 2):

Your `Ingress` resource looks good. I used the same setup as yours and received a message that `TLS 1.3` was supported.

The official documentation states:

> #### Default TLS Version and Ciphers
>
> To provide the most secure baseline configuration possible,
>
> nginx-ingress defaults to using TLS 1.2 and **1.3** only, with a [secure set of TLS ciphers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#ssl-ciphers).

Please check which version of `nginx-ingress-controller` you are running:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy: Detect installed version](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#detect-installed-version)*

Also you can check if `TLS 1.3` is enabled in `nginx.conf` of your `nginx-ingress-controller` pod (`ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;`). You will need to `exec` into the pod.

---

### Troubleshooting steps for ensuring support for `TLS 1.3`

---

#### Does your server (`nginx-ingress`) supports `TLS 1.3`?

You can check if your `Ingress` controller supports it by running an online analysis:

- *[SSLLabs.com: SSLTest: Analyze](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)*

You should get a message stating that `TLS 1.3` is supported:

[image: ANALYSIS]

You can also use alternative online tools:

- *[Geekflare.dev: TLS test](https://gf.dev/tls-test)*
- *[Geekflare.com: 10 Online Tool to Test SSL, TLS and Latest Vulnerability](https://geekflare.com/ssl-test-certificate/)*

---

#### Does your client supports `TLS 1.3`?

Please make sure that the client connecting to your `Ingress` supports `TLS 1.3`.

The client connecting to the server was not mentioned in the question:

- Assuming that it's a **web browser**, you can check it with a similar tool to the one used for a server:

  - *[Clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443: SSLTest: ViewMyClient](https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html)*
- Assuming that it is some other tool (`curl`, `nmap`, `openssl`, etc.) please check  its documentation for more reference.

---

Additional reference:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress nginx: Enable tls 1.3 in the nginx image](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2384)*
- *[En.wikipedia.org: Wiki: Transport Layer Security Adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security_Adoption)*

Comment: The nginx controller only has TLSv1.2 active, I'll look into upgrading the ingress controller